# Adding a bar chart to a cartopy map

Tags: python, bar-chart, cartopy

Is there anyway to add a bar chart to a cartopy map?

Here is my code currently:

```
latN = 42.0
latS = 32.0
lonW = -125.0
lonE = -115.0
cLat = (latN + latS)/2
cLon = (lonW + lonE)/2

data_6 = all_data.loc[(all_data['temp'] >= 95)]
lats_6, lons_6 = data_6['event_lat'], data_6['event_lon']

data_6_a = data_6['Date'].groupby([data_6.Date.dt.month]).agg('count')
data_6_a = data_6_a.to_frame()
data_6_a.columns = ['Occurrences']
data_6_a = data_6_a.reset_index()
data_6_a.columns = ['Month', 'Occurrences']

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=cLon, central_latitude=cLat)
res = '10m'
fig_1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax_1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1,projection=proj)
ax_1.set_extent([lonW,lonE,latS,latN])
ax_1.add_feature(cfeature.LAND.with_scale(res))
ax_1.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN.with_scale(res))
ax_1.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale(res))
ax_1.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES.with_scale(res), alpha = 0.5)
ax_1.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale(res));
ax_1.set_title('Sites in California with Temperature Values Above 95 degrees F, 2020', fontsize=20)
ax_1.scatter(lons_6,lats_6,s=100,c='r',edgecolor='black',alpha=0.75,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I want to add a bar chart that shows the number of events by month to my cartopy map - which is of California - in the area of water portion of the map. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: More details about your data please. Do you want a bar chart that shows the values from `data_6_a` as '['Occurrences']` vs `['Month']`? If so, that can be done by creating 2 subplots on the figure using `plt.subplots(2)`. First subplot is your cartopy plot. Second subplot is the bar chart. To create the bar plot, use `plt.bar(x, height)` where x is ['Month'] values and height is ['Occurrences']` values.

Comment: Yeah, so the x-axis would be the column 'Month' from data_6_a, and the y-axis (or height) would be the column 'Occurrences'. I'll try that, thanks!